# How to control the size of ToolTip which appears when AutoEllipsis Enabled for Label in .Vb.Net

Tags: vb.net, label, tooltip

I Have a Label Control, and the text I pass to that Control is sometime larger then the viewable area of the control, I set 'AutoEllipsis" property True.

When I hover my mouse over to that control a long long ToolTip appears in front, which is quite annoying.

I want to control that behavior and want to wrap text to multi lines.
Kindly help anybody.

Comment: It is up to you to insert ControlChars.CrLf into the string where needed.

Comment: @HansPassant : But I didn't add any tool-tip control .Its automatically displaying tool-tip when AutoEllipsis Enabled

Comment: Of course, that's why you have to insert the line breaks yourself.

Comment: @HansPassant: Then Label Control overlaps

Comment: Hard to guess why, you normally should use AutoSize = False and the MaximumSize property to ensure that the ellipsis are displayed.  Which is the basic way to avoid overlap as well.

Answer (score 1):

After suggestion, I have think around and an idea came into my mind.
I broken string where text was going off the sight of Label region , but keeping in mind that very next of word completion so it wont add new line in the mid of word.

here is the code:

```
        Dim str As String = "Chorioactis is a genus of fungus that contains the single species Chorioactis geaster, an extremely rare mushroom found only in select locales in Texas and Japan. In the former, it is commonly known a"
        Dim startindex As Integer = str.IndexOf(" ", 100)
        Dim secondhalf As String = str.Substring(startindex, (str.Length) - startindex)
        Dim firsthalf As String = str.Substring(0, startindex)            
        str = firsthalf + Environment.NewLine + secondhalf

        Label1.Text = str
```

below are attached Images,
**Before**
[image: Before]
**After**
[image: After]

Before applying such sub-string operations, make sure to verify the string length is greater then to that number which we set to breakup line